# How to restart a group of processes when it is triggered from one of them in C code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec, fork

i have few processes *.rt written in C.

I want to restart all of them(*.rt) in the process foo.rt(one of the *.rt) in itself (buid-in C code)

Normally i have 2 bash scripts stop.sh and start.sh. These scripts are invoked from shell.

Here are the staffs of the scripts
stop.sh --> send kill -9 signal to all  "*.rt" files.
start.sh -->invokes processes named "*.rt"

My problem is how can i restart all rt's from C code. Is there any Idea to restart all "*.rt" files triggered from foo.rt file ?

I tried to use this in foo.rt but it doesnt work. ***Because stop.sh is killing all *.rt files even if it is forked as a child which is deployed to execute start.sh script***

```
...
case 708: /* There is a trigger signal here*/
    {
        result = APP_RES_PRG_OK;
        if (fork() == 0) { /* child */
           execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c","/sbin/stop.sh",NULL);
           execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c","/sbin/start.sh",NULL);// Error:This will be killed by /sbin/stop command
           }
     }
```

Comment: The second execl() will never be executed (because the first one does not return, except when it fails)

Comment: Your second execl is probably never running.   If the first execl succeeds, it never returns.

Comment: Ok. What am i supposed to do to restart *.rt's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'have solved problem with "at" daemon in Linux

I invoke 2 system() calls stop & start.

My first attempt was faulty as explained above. execl make a new image and never returns to later execl unless it is succeed

Here is my solution

```
case 708: /*There is a trigger signal here*/
{
            system("echo '/sbin/start.sh' | at now + 2 min");
            system("echo '/sbin/stop.sh  | at now + 1 min");
 }
```

Comment: At the very least, you should swap the two above calls to `system`: register the `stop.sh` *before* registering the `start.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [process groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group), at least if all your related processes are originated by the same process...

So you could write a glue program in *C* which set a new process group using [setpgrp(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgrp.2.html) and store its pid (or keeps running, waiting for some IPC).

Then you would stop that process group by using [killpg(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html).

See also the notion of session and [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html)